# Picklist value is not displaying using @wire in LWC for a specific user

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lwc-wire-adapter

{"status":403,"body":{"message":"You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.","statusCode":403,"errorCode":"**INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS**"},"headers":{},"ok":false,"statusText":"Unexpected HTTP Status Code: 403","errorType":"**fetchResponse**"}

I am getting the above console error when trying to use OOTB wire method to fetch the picklist value for a user having standard profile(with all CRUD Permission on field & object). User is accessing this component inside the salesforce.(not on community)

Below code is working properly for System Administration & showing the picklist value.

```
import { LightningElement,wire,track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Claim.Status';
export default class PickLst extends LightningElement {
    @track fieldsInfo;
    value;
    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '0128c000002wSoiAAE', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
        propertyOrFunction({error, data}){
            if(data){               
                this.fieldsInfo = data.values.map(option => ({
                    label: option.label,
                    value: option.value
                }));
            }
            else if (error) {
                console.log('Error in Picklistval==>'+JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        }

        handleChange(event) {
            this.value = event.detail.value;
        }
}

HTML 
<template>  
        <lightning-combobox
                name="fieldInfo"
                label="field label"
                value={value}
                placeholder="Select field label"
                options={fieldsInfo}
                onchange={handleChange} >
        </lightning-combobox>        
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue that FSC permission set is not included for the user.